# Security settings in Storm to connect to secured Kafka Cluster

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, apache-storm

*Background* :

I am working on kafka-Storm project. Storm reads messages from secured kafka cluster.
SSL security was implemented in Kafka broker. Consumers (In our case it is Storm) has to provide the necessary information to get secured connection to kafka broker.

Client has to provide below details as configs. All these details in a property file and configure the property file as kafka.client.security.properties.

## Keystore file

keystore=Location of certificate

keystorePwd=keystorepassword

keyPwd=keypassword

## Truststore file

truststore=Location

truststorePwd=TrustStorePassword

*Questions* :

My consumer is Trident Storm and i am trying to provide these details to get a secured connection.
Does storm support this ?

Can i give SSL details any where in storm as properties or configurations ?
How can i read messages from such secured kafka broker which as SSL layer ?